# Backbone: Wait for multiple updates

Tags: backbone.js

I am writing a simple application in Backbone.js and have come across a frustrating situation where my functions bound to the change events are being fired before each model attribute is changed.

In summary, my component is bound to a datepicker, and takes in a start date and end date. I want to wait until both the start date and end date are set, but using the change event fires before both have been set.

Here is some pseudo-code:

```
define(["jquery", "underscore"], function () {
var model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function (options) {
        this._super();

        //Make the items null
        this.set("startDate", null);
        this.set("endDate", null);

        //Listen for changes to data
        this.on("change:startDate change:endDate", this.prepareData, this);
    },
    prepareData: function() {
        var startDate= this.get("startDate");
        if (!startDate)
            return;

        var endDate= this.get("endDate");
        if (!endDate)
            return;

        //DO MY STUFF
    }
});
```

The result of this is that the first time the 'prepareData' function is fired, I have the new start date and the old end date.

Any clues?

EDIT:

The added complication is that sometimes only date date will be changed, for instance where the user selects a range that lands on the same end date as previously. Seems like I need to wait for a period to check for changed before triggering the function.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the old dates in your model (this._startDate & this._endDate) to check if they have changed :

```
prepareData: function() {
    var count = 0;
    var startDate= this.get("startDate");
    if (startDate == this._startDate)
        count++;

    var endDate= this.get("endDate");
    if (endDate == this._endDate)
        count++;

    if (count == 0) {
        return;
    } else if (count == 1) {
        // here set your timeout
    }

    this._startDate = startDate;
    this._endDate = endDate;

    //DO MY STUFF
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful but wouldnt account for the scenario where the end date is the same (say the user just just changes that start date). In that case nothing would run. How can I wait for a period of time?

Answer (score 0):

The fact you are registering "change:startDate change:endDate" doesn't mean that the event would be fired only if both of them have changed. They're separeted events, so when the "change:startDate" occur your prepareData function is called and also when the "change:endDate" occur. 
This is why the first time the prepareData function is called the endData has the old value.

Comment: Thanks, but that is exactly my problem. I need to be able to wait to see if both dates are being updated, or just one.